# Do while loop doesn't loop through all lines of code, but just for one?

Tags: bash, shell, loops, awk

I have a file with content like

```
[path-to-file] [filesize]
/home/jochen/project/tests/test_m.py 8888
/home/jochen/project/tests/test_url.py 2453
/home/jochen/project/tests/testsupport/init.py 0
/home/jochen/project/tests/testsupport/test.py 5766
```

that I want to manipulate with bash scripting.

As output I want to have the file content separated:

```
$ the filesize
$ a sum: filesizesum 
$ the filepath
```

I play around with various expressions and this is the current version of the loop:

```
while read k ; 
    do   
            awk '{print $2 }'; #Filesize
            awk '{ p += $2}; { print p }'; # Filesize sum up to here
            echo $k | awk '{print $1 }'; # Filepath
    done < FileWithInputData
```

My trouble is:
I can delete 2 of the 3 code lines between `do` and `done` and the remaining line works within the loop as expected. So every single line seems to be OK for me.
But when I use a combination of two lines or all three of them, the behaviour changes: only the first line is working and the loop does not run through the other.

But I cannot believe that I need to run three different loops to do that.

I could not find another thread that provides a solution, if i wrote a duplicate please redirect me. and I hope I could explain clear what my trouble is.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not clear, please mention your input and expected output more clearly in your post.

Comment: Where does `filesizebefore` come from?

Comment: `awk '{print $2 }'`or `awk '{ p += $2}; { print p }'` don't have any input from stdin or a file so they are basically just going to hang forever waiting for that missing input from stdin.

Comment: tried to clarify. I hope you can understand better now.

Comment: @JamesBrown what you describe could be the case - my output fits to that explanation. How can I solve this without running three different loops?

Comment: @Jochen, if you could add more sample of input and expected output then we could understand it better, to be honest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These awks in the `do...done`:

```
do
  awk '{print $2 }'; #Filesize
  awk '{ p += $2}; { print p }'; # Filesize sum up to here
  ...
done
```

don't do anything as they don't get any input from stdin and don't have files to process. Pick one way to call awk:

- `program | awk '{...}' # reads from stdin`
- `awk '{...}' file      # processes a file`
- `awk 'BEGIN{...}       # all code within the BEGIN block`

At the moment they are basically hanging forever waiting for that missing input.

Good news is that you don't need the bash loop at all. Awk is (can be) a loop by itself iterating all records of a given file. At shortest you just need to:

```
$ awk '{print $1,p+=$1,$2}' file
```

for example:

```
$ echo -e 1 path1\\n2 path2\\n3 path3 | awk '{print $1,p+=$1,$2}'
1 1 path1
2 3 path2
3 6 path3
```

or if you want the items each on its own line, add `BEGIN{OFS=ORS}`:

```
$ echo -e 1 path1\\n2 path2\\n3 path3 | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=ORS}{print $1,p+=$1,$2}'
1
1
path1
2
3
path2
3
6
path3
```